# How can I use less lines of code in this code? (It's from the famous rice chess fable)

Tags: python, loops

I want to avoid recursion, but I'm happy to use for loops. I'm writing to file for a reason, so it must stay.

```
count =1
b = 1
total = 0
while count <65:

 b = b*2
 total = total +b
 print ("Square number is:",count)
 print ("rice on that square",b)
 print ("total so far:", total)
 count +=1
 f = open("rice.csv", "a")
 f.write(str(b)+ "\n")
 f.close()

print ("all together that  ",total,"grains of rice")

kg = total/33000

cost = kg * 1.20

print ("that is £", cost,", thank you very much!")
```

Comment: What is the problem? Why isn't this sufficient? It's already less than 20 lines.

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for improvements, you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be an excessive amount of code. I don't see that you could reduce it very much.

Comment: You could make little changes like `count, b, total = 1, 1, 0` or `print(f"Square number is: {count},\nrice on that square {b},\ntotal so far:{total}")`, but still - why you would need to do that? Maybe if you say something more about your use case, we could help better.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I changed the mode for `open` to `w` as you are opening it only once.

```
total = 0
with open("rice1.csv", 'w') as f:
    for i in range(64):
        b = 2**(i+1)
        total += b
        print("Square number is:", i+1)
        print("rice on that square",b)
        print("total so far:", total)
        f.write(str(b)+ "\n")

print ("all together that  ",total,"grains of rice")

cost = total/33000  * 1.20

print ("that is £", cost,", thank you very much!")
```

Comment: Did you mean: `b = 2**(i+1)`?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to use a context manager to open the file. That way it autimatically closes itself.

```
with open("rice.csv", "a") as file:
    file.write(str(b)+ "\n")
```